# Azure DataFactory v2 Linked Service with Integration Runtime

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Self Hosted IR Setup on Client Server, shows connected to my ADFv2.
Creating Linked Service times out. Only difference i can see between this setup and previous successful setup is that SQL Connection requires trust server certificate tick enabled.

I dont know how to add trust server certificate to my json sqlconnection file.

Removed Servername and password below for SqlServerLinkedService.json

```
{
"properties": {
    "type": "SqlServer",
    "typeProperties": {
        "connectionString": {
            "type": "SecureString",
            "value": "Server=<servername>;Database=Master;User 
ID=admin;Password=<password>;Timeout=60"
        }
    },
    "connectVia": {
        "type": "integrationRuntimeReference",
        "referenceName": "Test-IR"
    }
},
"name": "SqlServerLinkedService"
}


New-AzureRmDataFactoryV2LinkedServiceEncryptedCredential -DataFactoryName 
$dataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName - 
IntegrationRuntimeName "TEST-IR" -File ".\SQLServerLinkedService.json
" > encryptedSQLServerLinkedService.json
```

Gives me the error:

```
 New-AzureRmDataFactoryV2LinkedServiceEncryptedCredential : Unable to 
connect to the remote server caused by A connection attempt failed because 
the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 
<ip address removed>:8050 At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmDataFactoryV2LinkedServiceEncryptedCredential -DataFactory ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New- 
AzureRmData...yptedCredential], GeneralException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :
```

Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.NewAzureDataFactoryLinkedServiceEncryptedCredentialCommand

Answer (score 0):

You could use TrustServerCertificate in your connection string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax#using-trustservercertificate